# wamp 404 this webpage is not available

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver

I have installed wamp a handful of times, and have it working on my local environment. Currently I am attempting to resolve an issue on a server of mine which is running wamp. I uninstalled a working copy, and now when I attempted to reinstall I have been unsuccessful. I have changed the port to be 8080 and have configured the httpf.config to do so.

```
ServerName 50.56.176.95:8080

ServerRoot "C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9"

Listen 50.56.176.95:8080

<virtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/Hi"
    ServerName 50.56.176.95
</virtualHost>
<virtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/Hi"
    ServerName 50.56.176.95
    <directory "c:/wamp/www/Hi">
        Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
       Require all granted
    </directory>
</virtualHost>
```

Wamp turns on and apache and php start up, however if I attempt o access 50.56.176.96:8080 I will get a 404 error.

Something to note is that everything is commented out in the htacces file in the www directory.

Comment: In ServerName you have ip: 50.56.177.95:8080, then you have other(50.56.176.95:8080) in Listen directive. So it's 176 or 177?

Comment: Sorry its 176, I changed up the ip address but forgot to change all of them

Answer (score 0):

Should the ServerName not actually be a name and not an ip address?

Also you are using Apache 2.2 and Apache 2.4 access control syntax in the same VH def? As you are using Apache 2.4 it may be best to stick to 2.4 syntax.

So maybe this will work :-

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/Hi"
    ServerName hi.com
    ServerAlias www.hi.com
    <Directory "c:/wamp/www/Hi">
       Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```